# BGL Bundled Properties add_edge "no matching function"

Tags: boost, boost-graph

I have created a struct, and used it as a template parameter to adjacency_list. However, when I try to add_edge(vertex1, vertex2, property, graph) , the compiler complains "no matching function call". Can anyone see where I've gone wrong here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>

// Create a struct to hold several properties
struct MyProperty
{
  int MyIntProperty;
};

// Define the type of the graph
typedef boost::adjacency_list<boost::vecS, boost::vecS, boost::undirectedS, MyProperty> Graph;

int main(int,char*[])
{
  // Create a graph object
  Graph g(2);

  // Add an edge between node 0 and node 1 with weight 1.2
  MyProperty p;
  p.MyIntProperty = 5;
  std::cout << p.MyIntProperty << std::endl;
  add_edge(0, 1, p, g);

  return 0;
}
```

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this code, `MyProperty` is declared as a vertex property rather than an edge property, and so it doesn't make sense to insert edges with that property.  Try adding `boost::no_property` before `MyProperty` in your `adjacency_list` typedef.